# FUSE: ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack

Tags: python, ubuntu, fuse

I'm following this tutorial related to FUSE.

```
https://www.stavros.io/posts/python-fuse-filesystem/
```

In the tutorial mentioned above, it simply copies everything from specified directory to the mount point. I'm trying to tweak this a bit. Instead of copying from one directory to moint point, I'll be creating files against every key in leveldb. Content of these files will be value of corresponding key. So far, I have only tried changing body of readdir().

```
 def readdir(self, path, fh):
        print "inside readdir"
        self.db = plyvel.DB('/tmp/testdb/', create_if_missing=True)
        return self.db.iterator(start=b'0'); #Statement which causes error
```

Following is the traceback:

```
inside readdir
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fuse.py", line 495, in _wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs) or 0
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fuse.py", line 698, in readdir
    name, attrs, offset = item
ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. If I use print statement to print r in the original code, I simply get all the filenames one by one. Following is the original code:

```
def readdir(self, path, fh):
        full_path = self._full_path(path)

        dirents = ['.', '..']
        if os.path.isdir(full_path):
            dirents.extend(os.listdir(full_path))
        for r in dirents:

            print r
            yield r
```

I believe that the offset part is missing from the iterator that I am returning. If so, then how do I append that to the iterator?
I am using fusepy and plyvel
How to run:
You should have plyvel installed. Create a dummy database in tmp folder. Add keys ranging from 0 to 100 and corresponding dummy values. Copy paste the original code and change the body of readdir() to the one I have mentioned.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The code you have shown does not contain the line which causes the error.

Comment: Just added the comment. It's the return statement

Comment: Just changed return statment to yield str(self.key+1) since I want to iterate over keys. Not really sure whether this will raise logical error later on or not but for now this does the trick